# Insert objects in specific order with map

Tags: dictionary, go, hashmap, mapping

I have a use case where the order of objects needs to be in a specific order. The current implementation is done with using `map` and I've found numerous posts and articles where it states that `map` are an unordered list. All of the solutions that I found are those where they've made the keys as integers and they've used `sort.Ints(keys)` to sort by keys.

In the code, I'm using a yaml template to instantiate a dictionary pair, then passing it into the ProcessFruits function where it does the logic.

How would I go about getting the desired result (see below) where the object from the top of the list in fruits.yml.tmpl will always be first?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
//Filename: fruits.yml.tmpl

fruits: {{ $fruits := processFruits
  "oranges"    true
  "bananas"    false
  "apples"    true
  }}
  {{ $fruits }}
```

```
//Filename: fruits.go

func ProcessFruits(fruits map[string]interface{}) (interface{}) {
  keys := make([]string, len(fruits))

  i := 0
  for fruit := range fruits {
    keys[i] = fruit
    i++
  }

  sort.Strings(keys)
  fmt.Println(keys)
}
```

```
// Connect fruits.yml.tmpl to the ProcessFruits function
tmpl, err := template.New(t).Funcs(template.FuncMap(map[string]interface{}{
    "processFruits":        ProcessFruits,
})).Funcs(sprig.TxtFuncMap())
```

**Actual Results:**

[apples:true bananas:false oranges:true]

**Desired Results:**

[oranges:true bananas:false apples:true]

**Go Playground**

https://go.dev/play/p/hK2AdRVsZXJ

Comment: Code has been added.. I didn't think that it was useful, so I didn't include it in the original post.

Comment: You can create a slice in that code when you're parsing the fruits.yml.tmpl

Comment: The template errors out before calling the function `ProcessFruits`.  The template attempts to call `ProcessFruits` with six arguments, but `ProcessFruits` has one argument.  Edit the question to show your actual code.

Comment: you can create a slice to order your map on your .tmpl

Comment: @RahmatFathoni I already have a slice in fruits.go `keys := make([]string, len(fruits))`  Is that what you meant?

Comment: The code does not compile.  Where is that map coming from?   Can you change it to a slice.

Comment: the input parameter of the function ProcessFruits is map so the range loop will be random... you need to change the logic.. if you insist on using map then you need to read the yaml to slice first then chang it to map ...

Comment: hm.. the yaml is a dictionary type with a key,value pair, so I'm not sure if a slice would accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but I think I've figured out a working code to my problem. What I've done was creating another dictionary that will keep track of the order of the "fruits", then combining the two dictionary together with a nested for loop and output the result to a slice.

Here's my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func ProcessFruits(fruits map[string]interface{}, counts map[int]string) {
    keys := make([]string, len(fruits))
    var foo []string
    var baz []int

    for k := range fruits {
        foo = append(foo, k)
    }
    for _, k := range foo {
        fmt.Println("Key-string:", k, "Value-bool:", fruits[k])
    }

    fmt.Println("==========================")

    // Iterate over counts (keys are ints)
    for l := range counts {
        baz = append(baz, l)
    }
    sort.Ints(baz)
    for _, l := range baz {
        fmt.Println("Key-int:", l, "Value-string:", counts[l])
    }

    fmt.Println("==========================")
    // Correlate list with sorted integer keys with the other list that contains true/false

    i := 0
    for _, m := range baz {
        for _, n := range foo {
            //fmt.Println("Key-int:", m, "Value-string:", counts[m])
            //fmt.Println("Key-string:", n, "Value-bool:", fruits[n])

            if counts[m] == n {
                keys[i] = n
                i++
                //fmt.Println(i)
            }

        }
    }

    // Desired results is now in the slice, keys.
    fmt.Println(keys)

}

func main() {

    var m = map[string]interface{}{
        "oranges": true,
        "bananas": false,
        "apples":  true,
    }

    var n = map[int]string{
        0: "oranges",
        1: "bananas",
        2: "apples",
    }

    ProcessFruits(m, n)

}
```

If anyone has a better solution, then I'd be curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the usage of sort.Reverse() and sort.StringSlice()

```
func main() {
    keys := []string{"bananas", "apples", "oranges"}
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.StringSlice(keys)))
    fmt.Println(keys)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/n08S7xtbeij

See: https://pkg.go.dev/sort#example-Reverse

Comment: I think he want the order to be according  to the list from yaml not according to reverse alphabet

Comment: Correct. I want the order to be according to the list in the yaml file

Comment: Ah my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are passed as a slice. Collect every other argument as a string and print:

```
func ProcessFruits(args ...interface{}) interface{} {
    var fruits []string
    for i, arg := range args {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            fruits = append(fruits, arg.(string))
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(fruits)
    return nil
}
```